# Ionic: proxy servers on android

Tags: ionic-framework, proxy, network-programming, ionic2

I have a project setup to hit a local server also in development on port 3000. In development I used the following configuration in the proxy settings of `ionic.config.json` to avoid CORS issues:

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.1.14:3000/api"
    },
    {
      "path": "/auth",
      "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.1.14:3000/auth"
    }
  ]
```

However when I run this on an android device it seems to insist on ignoring these settings and calling `file:///auth/...` instead of the real URL. This is fixed with entering the IP address manually. Is there any way to streamline the process and have a fixed set of working URL's on both `ionic serve` and the native app?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you found any fix for this one?

Comment: I used a global constant that was set to "" for development and the URL (real DNS endpoint) in production

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it using `Platform.is()` method. When the device is android, I change the url to contain ip address of my api.

*ionic.config.json*

```ts
"proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.80.10:3000/api"
  }
]
```

My example service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class MemberService {
  private url = 'api/members';

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {
    if(this.platform.is('android')) {
      this.url = 'http://192.168.80.10:3000/' + this.url;
    }
  }

  getMembers(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}.json`)
      .toPromise()
      .then(result => result.json())
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

Probably `this.platform.is('mobile')` will be also good.